# Dismiss an ionic page and reached to a previous page, constructor does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

i am using ionic 3 and i am trying to get value on the previous page but the constructor is not working, i also tried  `ionViewDidEnter(){}` and
`ionViewDidLoad(){}`

i was moving my value through local storage and was calling it in the constructor and `ionViewDidEnter(){}`
`ionViewDidLoad(){}` of the previous previous page

```
 this.locationvalue =localStorage.getItem('locationName')
  console.log(this.locationvalue);
  localStorage.removeItem('locationName');
```

I am using google chrome to application mode to read my localStorage and i am able to read my value there.

Comment: Sorry your title and question do not complement each other (i.e. infer same thing). Read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). There's also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what do you mean get a value on previous page? are you returning value from current page?

Comment: I am moving to the next page and taking some value and trying to get that value back in the previous page's constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Perhaps have a look at [NavParams](https://saniyusuf.com/ionic-by-component-navigation/) as a better solution to local storage for this.

2) If not applicable because of multiple updates, I suspect if you are using local storage and you are **NOT** using a `Promise` with `NavPop` inside the `then()`.

local storage service:

```
removeItem(...):Promise<any> {
   return new Promise((resolve) =>{
         ...
  }
}
```

nested page doing return:

```
goBack():void {
 localStorage.removeItem('locationName').then(this.navCtrl.pop());
}
```

- You have to realise the local storage update is asynchronous and does not block. So by the time you return  to the prior page and render it, the local storage update, which I presume your *returned to page* is relying on to bind the data you display, will not have completed its update.
- The underlying JavaScript Event Loop at the foundation of this.
  Take a loop at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&t=1s).

3) Finally if you are confused by the Ionic Page lifecycle, [this](https://saniyusuf.com/ionic-by-component-page-lifecycle/) blog post may help too.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: let me try these,  and yes i forgot about the NavParams